# invoked function is not working in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

am calling the function of a form from another form. It executes but do not really show up. so any suggestions??

My code goes like

In Form FrmA

```
private void Print()
{
 FrmMenu ObjMain = new FrmMenu();
 ObjMain.Show();            
 }

public void CreateButtons(string Action)
{
  btn.Text=Action;
 }
```

And When the Form FrmMenu gets open then another function gets executed in constructor of FrmMenu

```
 Public FrmMenu()
 {
   FrmA f2 = new FrmA();
   f2.CreateButtons("NEW");
  }
```

But nothing happens ...!!! The function CreateButtons executes but do not show any changes
The text of button remain the same.
so please help me out.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect to happen. What does `CreateButtons` do? You aren't showing `f2` in your code.

Comment: Anybody.. please help me out. I don't need votes. I only need solution.

Comment: I'm sure people would like to help you but you haven't given enough info to do that. You have ignored my question above so I certainly can't help.

Comment: You are only creating a local instance of `FrmA`, calling a function on it, then it goes out of scope without you actually doing anything with it. Of course you do not see anything, you are not showing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

You must pass the instance of `FrmA` into the constructor of `FrmMenu`.

In `FrmA`:

```
private void Print()
{
    FrmMenu ObjMain = new FrmMenu(this);
    ObjMain.Show();
}
```

In `FrmMenu`:

```
public FrmMenu(FrmA f2)
{
    f2.CreateButtons("NEW");
}
```